# Without using 'isnull' and find rows which are having null in a particular column

Tags: sql

How to find rows whose date column is null without using 'is null' in the query?

```
SELECT * FROM HR_OPERATING_UNITS WHERE date_to IS NULL;
```

In above query I want to use a binding variable which can have null in it.
So, expected query is:

```
SELECT * FROM HR_OPERATING_UNITS WHERE date_to=:P_TO_DATE;
```

But the above statement doesn't fetch any rows through, although there is null in that binding variable.

Comment: First: please DON'T WRITE EVERYTHING IN UPPERCASE - it's really really hard to read, it's considered **SHOUTING** at people, and it's rude. Secondly: for ***what database system*** is this? SQL is just the query language - used by many databases..... is it MySQL? Postgres? IBM DB2? Oracle? SQL Server? Firebird? Interbase? something else entirely??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard approach is to handle the variable being null separately:

```
SELECT * FROM HR_OPERATING_UNITS
WHERE date_to=:P_TO_DATE
OR (:P_TO_DATE IS NULL AND date_to IS NULL)
```

If you really must only have one reference to the variable:

```
SELECT * FROM HR_OPERATING_UNITS
WHERE COALESCE(date_to, '1900-01-01') = COALESCE(:P_TO_DATE, '1900-01-01')
```

Picking a value that will never appear in the `date_to` column as the dummy value.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question you want to filter whenever or bind variable is null, or not. If so, try the following:

```
 SELECT * FROM HR_OPERATING_UNITS WHERE (:P_TO_DATE IS NULL AND date_to IS NULL) OR (date_to=:P_TO_DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM HR_OPERATING_UNITS
WHERE coalesce(date_to,  '2000-01-01') = coalesce(:P_TO_DATE, '2000-01-01')
```

This assumes that `'2000-01-01'` is not a valid date value in `date_to`.

If both values are `NULL`, then the default date comparison is true.  If neither are `NULL`, then the comparison is the column to the value.  If one is `'NULL'`, then the comparison is to the default value which is false.

Comment: would using `coalesce` on `date_to` cause an index on `date_to` to not get used?

Comment: @1_CR . . . In most databases, "yes".  The "right" solution is the one suggested by Bohemian, but the OP explicitly states that s/he does not want to use `is null`.

Answer (score 0):

if the value is null use date min value:

```
ISNULL(date_to,cast('1753-1-1' as datetime)) = ISNULL(:P_TO_DATE,cast('1753-1-1' as datetime))
```

this is for sql server, maybe have to replace ISNULL with NVL