# FireDac and parameter in Where clause failing

Tags: delphi, interbase, firedac

I am trying to make a fairly simple query with an optional parameter in Interbase. I am using Firedac in Delphi 10 Seattle to call it.

```
SELECT STATUS_ID FROM TABLENAME
WHERE
  STATUS_ID=:STATUSID OR :STATUSID IS NULL
```

fails with `Dynamic SQL Error Code = -804 Unknown Datatype`.

I can isolate just the `:STATUSID IS NULL` part and it fails.

Setting the parameter to null with just `STATUS_ID=:STATUSID` works just fine so it is the `:STATUSID IS NULL` part that is throwing the error.

Comment: Why not just use a different query when you're not going to pass a parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve ? You can not test a :param inside a select! Only exists Fields are valid  But that makes sense: `SELECT STATUS_ID FROM TABLENAME WHERE STATUS_ID=:STATUSID OR STATUS_ID IS NULL`. You Know the value of `:STATUSID` so test it before the query.

Comment: @moskito-x He wants the behaviour of an optional parameter - ie: if the parameter is `NULL` then return all rows, otherwise return any that match.  I don't think it really makes sense to send a parameter all the way to the server to have *it* check the parameter and branch on that - I'd just use two separate queries, personally.  Easy enough at runtime to use the appropriate one.

Comment: @moskito-x Well, yes, the query is obviously malformed - your suggestion of `... OR STATUS_ID IS NULL`, while correctly formed, does not do what OP wants.  I just thought I would clarify what he was trying to do.

Comment: Just to ensure that I am wrong... List somewhere all parameters from your Query component. Probably you will find two entries of `STATUSID`.

Comment: When just doing a single query with 1 parameter this makes little sense, but when you have dozens of filter parameters it allows the user to pick what they want without building a string.

Answer (score 1):

Just remembered:

```
some_field = :some_param or :some_param is null
```

can be replaced by

```
some_field = coalesce(:some_param, some_field)
```

Yet another solution to try.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I came up with is to use zero as my 'all' clause.
WHERE
  STATUS_ID=:STATUSID OR :STATUSID=0;

that works. Null is better because it is correctly asking for No Entity, but it seems the implementation in Firedac does not support it.

Comment: Please look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17489213/1322642 WHERE STATUS_ID is NULL

Comment: I can not believe that some DB access library does not supports NULL parameters. Try to play with `ParamByName(...).Clear`, `ParamByName(...).IsNull := True` or something. Unfortunately (or fortunately depending on point of view) I haven't Delphi/FireDAC, only Lazarus/[SQLdb|ZeosDbo] so I can not provide more suggestions.

Comment: Re: please look... That is not the same problem.
Re: I can not believe... Get it and try it. It is processed client side before it is sent to the server, and this driver cant figure the request out. It does not try to parse the parameter and then put the result into context for SQL parsing. It seems to be trying to parse phrases with Parameters as part of the syntax pattern. That would explain this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very late answer. But I had a similar problem.

I guess your problem is because you test `STATUS_ID=:STATUSID` before `:STATUSID IS NULL`. Maybe it'll work with `(:STATUSID IS NULL) OR (STATUS_ID=:STATUSID)`

For numeric fields, I came up with a slightly different solution. For integer PKeys, often you never have a value of 0. Meaning you can either pass NULL or 0 and this will still return all rows. Lil more flexible.

```
SELECT * FROM WHATEVER
WHERE
((:ID IS NULL) OR (:ID <= 0) OR (:ID = ID))
```

For string fields, either NULL or '' (empty string) will return all rows.

```
SELECT * FROM WHATEVER
WHERE
((:STR IS NULL) OR (TRIM(:STR) = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(10))) OR (:STR = CLIENT_NI))
```

You can even chain them up like

```
SELECT * FROM WHATEVER
WHERE
((:ID IS NULL) OR (:ID <= 0) OR (:ID = ID)) AND 
((:STR IS NULL) OR (TRIM(:STR) = CAST('' AS VARCHAR(10))) OR (:STR = CLIENT_NI))
```

Probably a little less efficient than having a separate query for all scenarios, but if you're using an OK RDB, it'll optimize the parameter WHERE clause as static, and you won't lose much performance. I love this solution.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a cast

```
SELECT STATUS_ID 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE STATUS_ID=:STATUSID OR cast( :STATUSID as integer ) IS NULL
```

This works in firebird, so I guess that it should work in Interbase as well.

Comment: As @J... pointed out in a previous comment, he wants the behaviour of an optional parameter

Comment: Assume `:STATUSID= ` query `WHERE STATUS_ID=(invisible nothing) ` will give next SQL Error. Results in `WHERE STATUS_ID=  OR   is NULL` ?-------remember `0` is never `NULL`

Comment: Casting NULL to an integer results in 0 in most SQL dialects, so the comparison in the OR portion of your statement will never evaluate to true; therefore, it won't do what the poster wants.

Comment: @KenWhite "_Casting NULL to an integer results in 0_" - it is wrong at least for PostgreSQL and SQLite :) So I guess that `cast(null as <any type>) is null` is always true.

Comment: @KenWhite in firebird it does not cast to 0, you can try it with the following sentence:      select cast( null as integer ) from rdb$database

Comment: @figura4 But does that work with parameters?  Parameterized queries backtick things... can you `CAST(\`NULL\` AS INTEGER)`?

Comment: @J... I've tried the query in ibexpert with the parameters and it works perfect, whether you pass an integer value or null. BTW, I just used integer in the cast as an example. I think the cast should be done to the datatype of the column STATUS_ID. I'm going to try in Seattle with a test project.

Comment: @Abelisto : your queries shown are a little bit different from `WHERE
  STATUS_ID=:STATUSID OR :STATUSID IS NULL` ::  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17489213/1322642

Comment: Good try but it does not work.

In the end I used Where :STATUSID=0 instead. I prefer null but it doesnt work.